# To get html file in code behind and to get the content after removing html tags

Tags: asp.net

Hi guys
My application is a web application.In exam folder i have  *html* file that displays question paper, means it contains questions and answer options.

I want to read the content of *html* files' questions and answer options and save to database.

Can anybody help?
The html file looks like this

Export grade: 4
Export subject: Reading NGS

```
Item ID: 4RMINI0521080000000076
Group ID: passage_Bullying
Benchmark: LA.4.1.6.7
Webb's Cognitive Complexity:2
Item Type: Multiple Choice
Correct Answer: B
Item Stem
```

Read this sentence from the passage.

Bullying is when someone repeatedly says or does things to make someone else feel bad.

What is the base word for the word repeatedly?

Answer A

eat

Answer B

repeat

Answer C

ed

Answer D

re

```
   Item ID: 4RMINI0521080000000077
    Group ID: passage_Bullying
    Benchmark: LA.4.1.6.8
    Webb's Cognitive Complexity:2
    Item Type: Multiple Choice
    Correct Answer: D
    Item Stem
```

Read this sentence from the passage.

Common forms of bullying include:...

Which word has the OPPOSITE meaning of the word common?

Answer A

usual

Answer B

popular

Answer C

continual

Answer D

rare

The html source code look like this

```
<BODY>
<P><B>Export grade:</B> 4<BR><B>Export subject:</B> Reading NGS<BR><BR><BR></P><!-- ITEM_START -->
<P><B>Item ID:</B> 4RMINI0521080000000076<BR><B>Group ID:</B> 

passage_Bullying<BR><B>Benchmark:</B> LA.4.1.6.7<BR><B>Webb's Cognitive 
Complexity:</B>2<BR><B>Item Type:</B> Multiple Choice<BR><B>Correct Answer:</B> 
B<BR></P>
<P><B>Item Stem</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>Read this sentence 
from the passage.</P>

<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12pt"></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt; MARGIN-LEFT: 10pt" 
align=left><B>Bullying is when someone repeatedly says or does things to make 
someone else feel bad.</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12pt"></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>What is the base word 
for the word <I>repeatedly</I>?</P>
<P><B>Answer A</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>eat</P>
<P><B>Answer B</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>repeat</P>
<P><B>Answer C</B></P>

<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>ed</P>
<P><B>Answer D</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>re</P>
<P><BR><BR></P><!-- ITEM_START -->
<P><B>Item ID:</B> 4RMINI0521080000000077<BR><B>Group ID:</B> 
passage_Bullying<BR><B>Benchmark:</B> LA.4.1.6.8<BR><B>Webb's Cognitive 
Complexity:</B>2<BR><B>Item Type:</B> Multiple Choice<BR><B>Correct Answer:</B> 

D<BR></P>
<P><B>Item Stem</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>Read this sentence 
from the passage.</P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12pt"></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt; MARGIN-LEFT: 10pt" 
align=left><B>Common forms of bullying include:...</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12pt"></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>Which word has the 
OPPOSITE meaning of the word <I>common</I>?</P>
<P><B>Answer A</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>usual</P>

<P><B>Answer B</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>popular</P>
<P><B>Answer C</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>continual</P>
<P><B>Answer D</B></P>
<P style="MARGIN-TOP: 0pt; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" align=left>rare</P>
<P><BR><BR></P
</BODY>
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of the HTML file and what fields yo need to extract?

Answer (score 1):

Upload the file and read with the HTML parser

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ it provide best way to read contents from HTML doc..

Comment: What namespace to be added to get HtmlDocument

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();